# Why does the github API python POST request not work?

Tags: python, github, python-requests

I want to create a pull request on github using the API. The following `curl` command **does** work

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"  -H "Authorization: token ghp_abc...123" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/alex4200/hello-world/pulls \
  -d '{"head":"copyright_updater","base":"master","title":"Test PR curl"}'
```

but this python snippet **does not** work:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
    "Authorization": "token ghp_abc...123"
}
data = {
    "head": "copyright_updater",
    "base": "master",
    "title": "Test PR python"
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/alex4200/hello-world/pulls",
    headers=headers,
    data=data
)
print(response.text)
```

This command, with the **exact** same data as the `curl`, returns a 400 error with the message

```
{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request"}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried to use `json=data` instead of `data=data`?

Comment: Yes that worked. Seems AGAIN a tutorial/documentation is incorrect: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

Comment: Not every data you want to send must be in json format. The python library handles the conversion automatically depending on using `data` or `json` parameter

Comment: Indeed. `data` will probably work if you add `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to the headers.

Comment: So, my second(!) bug I found with documentations/tutorials today. And it is only 8:10 am ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point here. What is the bug in the documentation? It is totally valid to use `request` without `json` content. The link you posted says nothing about how to use all these parameters. It's just an overview and no tutorial. That's why the official page has examples to tell. E.g. you can use `data` and `json_dump` it by yourself or you can simply send it as serialized object but your request url does not accept it that way, hence your question came up. Your use case: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: I cannot use `data`. I have to use `json` for unknown reasons. Something is wrong here!

Comment: @Alex Please read what I have written. I already clarified it and this is no "unknown reason". Once again: This is because the backend, where you send your request to, needs `JSON` format. There are plenty of backends who don't need `JSON` format. If you use `data`, the API just serailizes it and sends it to the backend. This is valid on many backends, but it is no `JSON`. So, it does not fit your usecase but many other.

Comment: @enak Yes you seem to be right. I just wonder why things always have to be so unnecessarily complicated. Why not also use a parameter `json_data`, or `data_json` or many more?

Comment: @Alex You may not always agree with how an API is designed. My advice is to read the docs carefully and try to see the logic behind what they did, even if it's different from what you might have done. Their logic is pretty simple: pass `data` if you already have a string formatted the way it should appear in the POST body. Pass `json` instead if you have an object that you'd like to be automatically serialized into a string. The `json` parameter is just a shortcut for your convenience, it converts the value given to a string, and also sets the Content-Type for you.

Comment: @Alex It's very natural to be thrown off by the difference between e.g. a JSON object (which is a string like `'{"key": "value"}'` and a python dict, whose code representation looks very similar, but it is *not* a string: in memory it has a structure particular to python dicts. HTTP deals in strings only and so a conversion needs to take place.  The decision made by the designers of `requests` library is that `data` is used when you've already taken care of formatting the string yourself (which depends on the API you're calling); `json` can be used if you want the conversion done for you.